# Vuex getters real time updating audio.currentTime state

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to have audio player in Vuex store to use its data for output to custom audio player in a Vue components.

In Vuex store there is a state property `aplayer` that plays music.
`store.js` code:

```
state: {
  aplayer: new Audio()
},
getters: {
  getCurrentTime: state => state.aplayer.currentTime
}
```

In the component I want to display `aplayer.currentTime` the current song. I'm trying to get it by using the getter `getPlayer` in a computed properties.

`components.vue` code:

```
getCurrentTime() {
  return this.$store.getters.getCurrentTime;
}
```

But when output to the template, the current time freezes to 0. However, when I press "pause", the current time is displayed correctly.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue works best when observing *plain objects*, of which `Audio` is not. Vue cannot detect when the `currentTime` property changes.

From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> The object must be plain: **native objects such as browser API objects** and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with their own stateful behavior.

Your best solution would be to generate your own `currentTime` number property and synchronize its value to `audio.currentTime` periodically by using `setInterval` while the audio is playing, and clear the interval when the audio is paused.

Answer (score 0):

store.js

```
state: {
  aplayer: new Audio()
},
getters: {
  getCurrentTime: state => state.aplayer.currentTime
}
```

Component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>{{getCurrentTime}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

  export default {
    computed: {
      ...mapGetters(['getCurrentTime'])
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Now currentTime is always 0 (even after pressing the button "pause")